# how to prove that $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1} ^n \left( \sqrt[p] {\frac{n^p+k^{p-1}}{n^p}} -1 \right) = \frac{1}{p^2}$ for all $p \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, definite-integrals

I saw this problem $L:=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1} ^ n \left( \sqrt {\frac{n^2+k} {n^2}} -1 \right)$ and I was able to prove that the limit is $\frac{1}{4}$, I noticed my proof work for all  $p \in \mathbb{N}$ so I generalised the result for all $p \in \mathbb{N}$.

***my proof :***

> for all  $p \in \mathbb{N}-\{1\}$ ( if $p=1$ the answer is obviously $1$) $$L:=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1} ^ n\left( \sqrt[p] {\frac{n^p+k^{p-1}}{n^p}} -1 \right) =\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1} ^ n\left( \sqrt[p] {{n^p+k^{p-1}}} -n \right)$$since $(a^p -b^p)=(a-b)(a^{p-1} +a^{p-2}b+a^{p-3}b^2+ \dots+ b^{p-1})  \ \ \forall p \in \mathbb{N}$
> $$L =\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1} ^ n  \left( \frac{k^{p-1}}{\sum_{i=0} ^{p-1} (\sqrt[p] {{n^p+k^{p-1}}})^i n^{p-1-i}  }      \right) $$
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1} ^ n  \left( \frac{k^{p-1}}{\sum_{i=0} ^{p-1} (\sqrt[p] {{n^p+n^{p-1}}})^i n^{p-1-i}  }      \right) \leq L \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1} ^ n  \left( \frac{k^{p-1}}{\sum_{i=0} ^{p-1} (\sqrt[p] {{n^p}})^i n^{p-1-i}  }      \right) $$
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \left( \frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{\frac{1}{p}} -1}{\frac{1}{n} }\right)  \sum_{k=1} ^ n  \left( \frac{k^{p-1}}{n^{p}  }      \right)          \leq L \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}  \sum_{k=1} ^ n  \left( \frac{k^{p-1}}{ pn^{p}  }      \right) $$  $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{\frac{1}{p}} -1}{\frac{1}{n} }\right)$ is the definition of derivative of $ x^{\frac{1}{p}}$ at $1$ so it is equal to $\frac{1}{p}$ and$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1} ^ n  \left( \frac{k}{n   }      \right)^{p-1} $ is the Riemann sum of $ \int_0 ^1 x^{p-1}dx =\frac{1}{p} $. By squeeze theorem $L = \frac{1}{p^2}$

my question is: can this result be generalised for all $p \in \mathbb{R}$? I believe that the limit will still be $\frac{1}{p^2}$ for all $p \neq 0$ but I couldn't prove that I tried to turn $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1} ^n \left( \sqrt[p] {\frac{n^p+k^{p-1}}{n^p}} -1 \right)$ for all $p \in \mathbb{R}$ to integral but I couldn't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're interested in the sum $$ S_n(p) := \sum_{ k = 1}^n \left( 1 + (k/n)^{p-1}\cdot1/n\right)^{1/p} - 1.$$ Below I'll argue that for every $p > 0, \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n(p) = 1/p^2.$

The overall approach is similar to the one you take, but we replace the identity with bounds coming from an analysis of the function $$ f(u) := (1+u)^{1/p}$$ over the domain $[0,1]$. The main point is this:

> Lemma: For any $p >0,$ there exists a constant $C > 0$ such that it holds for all $u \in [0,1]$ that $$u f'(0) - Cu^2/2  \le f(u) - f(0)\le u f'(0) + Cu^2/2.$$
> Pf. Observe that $f$ is twice differentiable over the domain. Using the Lagrange form of Taylor's theorem, we know that for every $u$, there exists some $\alpha \in [0,1]$ such that $$ f(u) = f(0) + u f'(0) + \frac{u^2}{2} f''(\alpha u).$$ Let me define $C = \max_{u \in [0,1]} |f''(u)|.$ So long as $C$ is finite, this immediately yields the bound, since no matter what $\alpha$ is, $f''(\alpha u) \in [-C,C].$ But observe that $f''(u) = 1/p \cdot (1/p - 1) \cdot (1+u)^{-(2-1/p)} $ is indeed finite for all $u \in [0,1]$, and we're done.

In the following, I'll only argue that $\limsup S_n(p) \le 1/p^2$ using the upper bound above. The lower bound will follow in much the same way. To use the above Lemma,, note that each term in $S_n(p)$ is of the form $f(u) - f(0)$, where the $u$ is $(k/n)^{p-1}\cdot 1/n \in [0,1].$ So, we immediately conclude that $$ S_n(p) \le \sum_{k = 1}^n f'(0)  \left(\frac kn\right)^{p-1}\cdot \frac 1n +  \frac{C}{2} \left(\frac k n \right)^{2p - 2} \cdot \frac 1{n^2}.$$ You already know how to deal with the main term (and of course $f'(0) = 1/p$ always). So, we'll argue that for $$ T_n(p):= \sum_{k = 1}^n \left(\frac k n \right)^{2p - 2} \cdot \frac 1{n^2},$$ it holds that $\lim_{n \to \infty} T_n(p) = 0,$ from which the conclusion follows.

To see this, first, if $2p-2 \ge 0,$ then note that since $k/n \le1,$ we have $$ 0 \le T_n(p) = \sum_{k = 1}^n (k/n)^{2p-2} \cdot 1/n^2 \le \sum_{k = 1}^n 1 \cdot 1/n^2 = 1/n \to 0.$$ If instead $2p-2 < 0,$  then we have $$ T_n(p) =\sum_{k = 1}^n (k/n)^{-(2-2p)} \cdot 1/n^2 = n^{-2p}  \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k^{2-2p}}.$$

Now we can use basic properties of sums of the form $\sum 1/k^{\alpha}$ to conclude. Indeed, if $2-2p > 1,$ then $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty 1/k^{2-2p}$ is finite, giving the bound $T_n(p) \le \varphi(p) n^{-2p} \to 0,$ where $\varphi(p)$ is something depending only on $p$.

If $2 - 2p < 1$ then note that $$ \sum_{k = 2}^n \frac{1}{k^{2-2p}} \le \int_1^n \frac{1}{x^{2-2p}} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{n^{-(1-2p)} - 1}{2p-1},$$ yielding $$ T_n \le n^{-2p} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2p-1} + n^{2p - 1}{2p-1}\right) \le \psi(p) (n^{-2p} + n^{-1}) \to 0,$$ where again $\psi(p)$ depends only on $p$. Finally if $2-2p = 1,$ the integral above is $\log(n)$, but here too $n^{-2p} \log n \to 0$ for any $p > 0,$ and we're done.

---

I should perhaps note that for $p < 0,$ the sum diverges. There's the obvious issue about the definition of the $1/0$th power for $p = 0,$ but take the case of $p = -q$ for some $q>0$, and consider $$ R_n(q):= \sum_{k = 1}^n (1 + (k/n)^{-q-1}\cdot 1/n)^{-1/q} - 1.$$ First thing to see is that each term in $R_n$ is nonpositive: $k \le n$, so $1 + (k/n)^{-\mathrm{ve}} > 1$, so its inverse is less than $1$. Further, for $k \le n^{q/2(q+1)},$ we have $ 1 + n^{q}/{k^{q+1}} \ge n^{q/2},$ and so $$  (1 + n^{q}/{k^{q+1}})^{-1/q} \le (n^{q/2})^{-1/q} =  n^{-1/2} < 1/4$$ for large enough $n$. So, for $k \in [1:n^{q/2(q+1)}],$ the summand is $< -3/4,$ and for larger $k$, the summand is always nonpositive, so the sum is upper bounded by $- n^{q/2(q+1)},$ which explodes to $-\infty$ as $n$ grows since $q > 0$.

Comment: WOW! that was a great argument. thank you very much sir.